# C# elasticsearch query using Nest

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm using elasticsearch and now making client program to use C#.

In my case, I want to send a query like this.

```
{
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": {
    "_timestamp": "desc"
  }
}
```

and my C# code is here

```
var node = new Uri("http://MYELASTICSEARCH_IP:9200");
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node);
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
var responses = client.Search<respon>(s => s
            .Index("logstash-2017.04.25")
            .Type("log")
```

What should I do?

Comment: What is the result and what are you expecting? What do you *want* to do?

Comment: You will find these links useful: [how to write match all query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/master/writing-queries.html#_match_all_query), [sort usage](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/sort-usage.html) and [from and size usage](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/from-and-size-usage.html)